# Linter errors at facebook OpenGraph metatags

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

What i'm trying to achieve is just to have the logo at the Whatsapp web sharing. But it's not happening even though the facebook debugger shows the right pic. And it's showing some strange lint errors like the following :

[image]

And my tags are the following :

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxxxx"/>
  <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
  <meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR"/>
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.comprezipp.com/"/>
  <meta property="og:title" content="Comprezipp"/>
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Comprezipp"/>
  <meta property="og:description" content="Um jeito novo de fazer compras."/>
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://comprezipp.com/assets/images/logo_og_img.png"/>
  <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://comprezipp.com/assets/images/logo_og_img.png"/>
  <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png"/>
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="200"/>
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="200"/>
  <meta property="og:image:alt" content="Carrinho de Compras"/>

</head>
```

What am i doing wrong ? Is there something to do with the tag fb:app_id ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.comprezipp.com%2F currently shows only two warnings, both regarding a missing `og:image`. Try and change `og:image:secure_url"` to just `og:image`, explicitly specifying a “secure” version should not be necessary.

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.comprezipp.com%2F there currently is no `og:image` tag in what Facebook sees when scraping your URL.

Comment: Yes there is a og:image tag now. I was just testing without it. The error is the same even with og:image tag

Comment: You need to re-scrape, after you made such changes. Debug tool does not show any errors any more now, and does show the specified image. (Now whether that has an effect in WhatsApp immediately, or might need some more time until some additional cache in between the two systems might update itself, you’ll have to see.)